# How to filter a basic csv by columns

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, search, csv-simple

How do I filter by third column of the following file

```
list.txt [[ list of people ]]

billy baxter - @baxter - b.baxter@woods.com
james woods - @woods - j.woods@someother.com
```

I currently have

```
cat list.txt | grep @woods > results.txt
```

The prob is the second column also has @ symbol  so I cant search for @woods.
Also I rather not search for @... or regex as there may be a secondary email2 col which I don’t want to filter by

I simply want to filter and only get lines by the third col. Ideally somehow to filter only in the third col, but retrieve whole lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk to search by the third column

```
awk -F"-" '$3 ~ /@woods.com/' list.txt
```

Comment: Also in my script script.sh it wouldnt work, I removed the tilda ~ and it did. Not sure just thought Id mention it